# why nuget command throw Exception?

Tags: mono, nuget

I am using nuget on ubuntu and use rider as IDE. my IDE works perfectly by nuget in its nuget management panel and I can add and remove my packages using that without any problem. 
but when I run `nuget` command in my terminal I am getting this exception:

```
Could not resolve type with token 01000249
System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000249
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo:get_method_info (intptr,System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.GetMethodInfo (System.IntPtr handle) [0x00000] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.GetPseudoCustomAttributes () [0x00002] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetPseudoCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType) [0x0000d] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.IsDefined (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) [0x0003b] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.IsDefined (System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
  at Microsoft.Internal.AttributeServices.IsAttributeDefined[T] (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider attributeProvider, System.Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in <0007e672dd7f4959adc6f8103d9c843f>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo.IsExport (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider attributeProvider) [0x00000] in <0007e672dd7f4959adc6f8103d9c843f>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo+<GetExportMembers>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x001cd] in <0007e672dd7f4959adc6f8103d9c843f>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00018] in <63992662b765477a898ef49cdcc99ee2>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo.HasExports () [0x0000c] in <0007e672dd7f4959adc6f8103d9c843f>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo.IsPartDiscoverable () [0x0001d] in <0007e672dd7f4959adc6f8103d9c843f>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedModelDiscovery.CreatePartDefinitionIfDiscoverable (System.Type type, System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ICompositionElement origin) [0x0000a] in <0007e672dd7f4959adc6f8103d9c843f>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.TypeCatalog.get_PartsInternal () [0x00052] in <0007e672dd7f4959adc6f8103d9c843f>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.TypeCatalog.CreateIndex () [0x0000b] in <0007e672dd7f4959adc6f8103d9c843f>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00075] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally remove my mono and nuget by

> sudo apt purge mono-compelete
>
> sudo apt purge nuget

and then install only nuget by

> sudo install nuget